# Automatically logging in to pages which has htaccess in directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, authorization

I have a certain directory where I have `.htaccess` file. 
I want to write something in PHP, for example, that will allow me to log in automatically to my site and then I can go to other sites in this directory.

I know that I can use *http://user:pwd@mysite.com*, but it doesn't work on IE.

I tried to use a curl option, but I'm not sure how can I use it to get anything useful for me.

So do you have any ideas if and how I can do this? Any examples will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found yet explicit solution, but for now I have some workaround for this problem.
I used `.htaccess` file to write few rewrite conditions and rules. 
Then I have:

- `Authentication.php` - where is array of users, who have access to pages and where is function of checking if sent login and password are correct;
- `Router.php` - where is list of special pages which should be always accessible (especially when user is not logged in) and where is function `file_get_contents` to get whole code of certain page;
- `SessionCheck.php` - where is function of checking if user has his own token in session (whether he is logged in);
- `index.php` - there are checking all above functions.

The point is to redirect all pages (*.html, *.htm, etc.) to `index.php` file, which verifies if current user is logged in. If he is, then there is downloaded code of page (which he wants to see) and it is showing by using `echo` function.